# Tried Webscraping with XPATH, Nokogiri, Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have been tring to parse some information from the saferweb site and am having issues getting it to work.

If I can get the first value I can adapt it to get the rest...

This example should return `Carrier` right next to Entity Type

SOURCE:

```
http://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=MC_MX&query_string=733709
```

mechanize w/ hpricot

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'mechanize'
  require 'hpricot'
  agent = Mechanize.new
  page = agent.get('http://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=MC_MX&query_string=733709')
  @response = page.content
  doc = Hpricot(@response)
  a = (doc/"/html/body/p/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/center[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td")[0].innerHTML
  a
```

Nokogiri

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=MC_MX&query_string=733709"))
ebit = doc.at("/html/body/p/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/center[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td").text
puts ebit
```

Comment: And what do those examples actually return?

Comment: Looks like the page source has HTML elements in uppercase, `<HTML>...<BODY>` etc. XPath is case-sensitive, so that would explain why your XPath isn't matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the value columns all have the same CSS class, so it's probably easier to search using that. This works for me.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=MC_MX&query_string=733709"))
# Get Entity Type field
ebit = doc.at('.queryfield').text
# Get rid of all the white space
ebit.gsub!("\u00A0", "").strip!
puts ebit
```

Comment: ok that returns the first ('.queryfield').text  how would i grab the secound instance?

Comment: I think `#search` or `#css` instead of `#at` should get them all.